# i need __NSCFArray convert to an array. is it possible?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsarray

I need to get values from "readers" to an array,
 where readers :

```
@"readers":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[readersIds componentsJoinedByString:@","]],
```

where readersIds is an NSArray.

```
NSArray *test =[[[e.response objectForKey:@"acls"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"readers"];
```

Actually i need to get back readers values into another NSArray, when i try

```
     NSString *test =[[[e.response objectForKey:@"acls"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"readers"];
```

it shows __NSCFArray. Is there any way to get back as array ?

Comment: `__NSCFArray` is a private, concrete subclass of `NSArray`. Where do you actually see it?

Comment: NSArray *test =[[[e.response objectForKey:@"acls"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"readers"];
 here i see the problem. Actually both are same? __NSCFArray and nsarray?

Comment: Treat it like they're the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to convert `__NSCFArray` into `NSArray`. Just assume it's plain `NSArray` and use it like regular. Actually, I believe it's the way it's implemented behind the scenes.